# how to get today's start time?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to get today's start time, I do this by way as follow:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

do I have better way?

Comment: Sorry what's wrong with `datetime.now()`?

Comment: `datetime.now()` return `datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 25, 16, 2, 37, 654956)`, what I need is `datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 25, 0, 0)`

Comment: So isn't `datetime.now().date()` what you want?

Comment: @EdChum yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call `date()` on a datetime object to get just the date:

```
In [122]:    
import datetime as dt
dt.datetime.now().date()

Out[122]:
datetime.date(2015, 9, 25)
```

### EDIT

looking at this questions years later you can just use `today` from `datetime.date`:

```
In[5]:
import datetime
datetime.date.today()

Out[5]: datetime.date(2018, 11, 22)
```

Comment: It's date, not datetime.

Answer (score 5):

You can use datetime combine

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
dt = datetime.combine(date.today(), time.min)
```